# Discord js v13 Edit Channel Permissions for Bot

Tags: permissions, discord.js

Trying to add bot to the channel permissions. The code works with ADMINSTRATOR Permissions but not without.

Iam getting always a Missing Access Error

[Missing Access Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8cNF.png)

[Current Permissions:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxdKL.png)

Code:

```
 channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.user.id, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true, SEND_MESSAGES: true});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple, if the bot can't see the channel, it can't modify it. Same way as user can't modify existing channel if they can't see that channel.

That is also why it works with `ADMINISTRATOR` perms because that way bot can see every channel

Comment: I know that it works with ADMINISTRATOR but is there no other solution?

Comment: Prevent the bot from editing/accessing channels it has no perms/access to. Just check bots permissions related to server and/or channel